# What does "cannot be resolved to a type" mean, and how can I fix it? Java Android 4.0

Tags: java, android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, resolve

This is (supposed to be) a simple example of implementing a dialog in Android 4.0. This method onCreateDialog() overrides the method of the same name imported from android.app.Dialog;  This code won't compile and generates the error message shown in the comment below.  What does this error message mean and how can I fix it?
Thanks!

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case 0:
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setTitle("This is a dialog with a stupid message...")
        .setPositiveButton("Dig it",

//error message:
//DialogInterface.onClickListener cannot be resolved to a type
            new DialogInterface.onClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                            "Gotcha!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        )
```

Comment: Did you mean - `new DialogInterface().onClickListener()`

Comment: You missed the capital `O`, it should be `DialogInterface.OnClickListener`

Answer (score 3):

As the error is trying to tell you, there is no type named `DialogInterface.onClickListener`.

Java is case-sensitive; [you need a capital `O`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnClickListener.html).